# How to integrate an external app into IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, integration, intellij-plugin

I want to build an Android Studio plugin (IntelliJ plugin) which can open an external app by pressing the button. The external app is developed by myself and is quite small. I hope to integrate it to the IntelliJ plugin so users only need to install the plugin instead of installing the app explicitly.

So is it possible for me to package the app into the plugin? I have tried putting the .app file under the resources folder but I don't know how to open the app programmatically. Or is there any other way to achieve my purpose?

Comment: You can create a [custom action](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/working-with-custom-actions.html) in the IDE and bind a simple Java/Kotlin function on it, which opens your application.

Comment: Thanks! I have already created a java class under src to custom action and also put the .app file under the src directory. Can you share how to programmatically opens the application with JAVA. (Sry, I'm new to java and not so clear how to do so. Thank you so much~).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458622/starting-other-applications-with-java

Comment: Thanks for the information. But since my app is packed in the .jar file, I think I cannot directly open it. Is there any way to so? (Currently, my only idea is extracting the app from the .jar file to a directory in the system.)

Comment: It is not obligatory to store the app in .jar file. Just add a "helpers" folder with resources you need (.app file for example)

Comment: Can you elaborate this a little bit? When I put the app in the resources folder, intellij automatically pack it into the .jar file. If I understand your suggestion correctly, there is a way to generate a plugin without packing my app into the .jar file. So where should I put the "helpers" folders? In the same level with the src folder or somewhere else?

Comment: Solved the problem already. Thanks for your help! Adding the file and modifying build.gradle configuration works.